# Unity Dependency Resolver not working with Katana and WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, katana

I tried Unity 3 for a WebAPI hosted in Katana.

I get a exception that system.web.http cant be loaded on the Startup.

Anyone made this work?

```
HttpConfiguration apiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

apiConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
apiConfig.Formatters.Remove(apiConfig.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
apiConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
apiConfig.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(_container);

app.UseWebApi(apiConfig);
```

Comment: are you still seeing an issue here? I noticed you other question related to `Parameter binding not working in Web Api` and you seemed to gone pass through this issue...is this still an issue? if yes, could you share the more detailed error...

Comment: I didnt find a solution to this. I used autofac IOC instead as a temp solution and it had no problem. (autofac had a nuget packaged for webapi 5.0)

Comment: Target of innovations exception. Could not load System.Web.Http. I have seen the error once before related to owin stuff. I assume its something related to the versioning of dlls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Unity.WebAPI package, it depends on System.Web.Http v4.0. In order to use it in Web API v2, you need to add assembly binding redirect to web.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: The webapi is hosted in owin, i do not have a web.config.

Comment: Use app.config instead.